# How to state FactoryGirl fixtures for associated model data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, RSpec-rails 2 and FactoryGirl. I would like to generate some *Factory associated model data* related to accounts for users (in the `User` class I stated the `has_one :account` association) so to make possible to do the following in spec files:

```
let(:user) { Factory(:user) } 

it "should have an account" do
  user.account.should_not be_nil # Note: 'user.account'
end
```

At this time I have a `factories/user.rb` file like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user, :class => User do |user|
    user.attribute_1
    user.attribute_2
    ...
  end
end
```

and a `factories/users/account.rb` file like the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :users_account, :class => Users::Account do |account|
    account.attribute_1
    account.attribute_2
    ...
  end
end
```

**What is the *correct\common* way to state FactoryGirl data in order to handle RoR associated models in spec files?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the :class => User, since it will be inferred automatically.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    attribute_1      'Some'
    attribute_2      'Text'
  end
end
```

To use associations in your factory, just include the name directly:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    user
    title    'Hello'
    body     'World'
  end
end
```

In the example above the user will be associated with the post.

You can also use named factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    association :user, :factory => :administrator
    title    'Hello'
    body     'World'
  end
end
```

The [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) explains it all.